# iPhoto doesn't get the gps data of photos

Tags: photos.app

I have a photo camera which store the gps data for each photo. It seems to me me that iPhoto is not aware of the gps data when I import the photos.

Is there anyway to make Places to work with the gps data of the photo?

Comment: What camera? Where does it write the gps data to on the photo?

Comment: It's a panasonic DMC-TZ10. I think the data is in the photo metadata, not sure though

Comment: Have you verified that the GPS data is actually written to the photo metadata (you can check in e.g. Preview)? It should be in the EXIF headers.